# Iterate over IDs and generate a report pdf for each ID using PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

This code generates one pdf for the first employee with his id in the url address. I would like to iterate over many ids and generate several pdfs one per each employee with unique id.

The records of employees are is a CSV file which has been read and parsed somewhere else. Also for iteraring over ids I have created an array containing ids which is called `idArray`. (e.g. `idArray = ['123', '127', '156']`). Would you please help me create a pdf per id from `idArray`?

```
var page = require('webpage').create(),
    system = require('system'),
    id = system.args[1];

page.open('http://127.0.0.1:3000/report.html?id=' + id, function () {

    var intervalHandle;

    // poll until
    var ready = function () {
        var ready = page.evaluate(function () {
            return reportReady;
        });

        if (ready) {
            clearInterval(intervalHandle);
            page.render('report-id.pdf');
            phantom.exit();
        } else {
            console.log("Not ready yet");
        }

    };

    intervalHandle = setInterval(ready, 100);

});
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you can't simply *iterate* over the IDs. `page.open()` is asynchronous, so you would tell PhantomJS to load the page with the next ID before the previous one can finished loading.

The solution is to use recursion. Define a function that contains the logic to do one iteration and use that to string many callbacks together:

```
var page = require('webpage').create(),
    system = require('system'),
    idArray = system.args[1].split(",");

iterate(); // let it run

function iterate() {
    var id = idArray.shift(); // changes the idArray
    page.open('http://127.0.0.1:3000/report.html?id=' + id, function () {
        var intervalHandle;

        // poll until
        var ready = function () {
            var ready = page.evaluate(function () {
                return reportReady;
            });

            if (ready) {
                clearInterval(intervalHandle);
                page.render('report-id.pdf');

                if (idArray.length > 0) {
                    iterate();
                } else {
                    phantom.exit();
                }
            } else {
                console.log("Not ready yet");
            }

        };

        intervalHandle = setInterval(ready, 100);
    });
}
```

I assume that the IDs are passed in this way:

```
$ phantomjs script.js 4,8,15,16,23,42
```